# Showing ok cancel Dialogbox through thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an Android service which spawns a thread.This thread waits for network data and after receiving that data I want to show Ok Cancel Dialogbox.

I was getting exception can't create handle that should have `Looper.prepare()`.I added `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` then now I am not getting any exception but its waiting infinitely.

Comment: please show the code and also the logcat error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a sole thread it's better to use an AsyncTask which is also a speacialized thread for Android.

You can wait for data in the AsyncTask's `doInBackGround` method and when you received data you can call `publishProgress()` which will invoke `onProgressUpdate` method of AsyncTask.

At `onProgressUpdate` you can update the UI without blocking the main thread and also this is the preferred way of doing long time operations in background like network listening etc.

Check AsyncTask for more info and how to use it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the UI thread(showing alert dialog) in non-UI thread by using handlers as like below code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
         { public void run() 
         { 
            try {
                ///do your stuff in 

                     mHandlerShowDialog.post(mUpdateShowDialog);
            ///do your struff
        }
      } ).start();


final Handler mHandlerShowDialog= new Handler();

     final Runnable mUpdateShowDialog = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
        // show your dialog here
         }
     };
```